# user-profile-edit.tpl.php not working for user#1

Tags: theming, users

I am going crazy on this one :-/

I have overridden my user edit page with a user-profile-edit.tpl.php

In my template I have:

```
function mytheme_theme() {
  $items = array();
  $items['user_profile_form'] = array(
    'render element' => 'form',
    'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'mytheme') . '/template',
    'template' => 'user-profile-edit',
    'preprocess functions' => array(
      'mytheme_preprocess_user_profile_form'
    ),
  );
  return $items;
}
```

My problem is that my user-profile-edit.tpl.php is not being picked up by user#1,
it is working however for all other authenticated users.

Is there some setting i am overlooking here?

Comment: Is the theme same for admin and authenticated users ?

Comment: Cool! Writing the answer for the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your themes are different for your users because the template name is fine.
It will work fine with the theme in which you have added the template.